# package com.x.y.z does not exist

Tags: java, servlets, war, resin

I'm trying to run old servlet under resin. I have deployed it as a war file. After starting resin there is a dir ic. It contains Webcontent dir with WEB-INF/lib/ic.jar (fatjar), jsp etc. While extracting this ic.jar I see there package com/x/y/z but while trying to access servlet page I'm getting an error: package com.x.y.z does not exist. 
Can anyone give me any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The jar needs to be in WEB-INF/lib, not in WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

When extracting the JAR file, you should see

```
com/x/y/z/ClassName.class
```

not

```
com.x.y.z/ClassName.class
```

Assuming that what you wrote wasn't a summary of what you saw (or a typo).